# Eclipse Juno - gaps in toolbar after update

Tags: eclipse-juno

I've just updated my **Eclipse IDE for Java Developers** plugin to version `1.5.1.20121004-1506` which resulted in ridiculous gaps in the main toolbar:

[image]

Yes, I know it's basically a bad idea to update Eclipse past Indigo, because each new version appears to be progressively worse and worse, but is there any simple way to fix this other than reinstalling some older version (I really don't want to lose my settings and installed plugins)? Is this bug tracked somewhere?

Comment: Since updating to Kepler, I haven't experienced this issue anymore. So whoever still has problems with it, should update to Kepler or Luna...

Answer (score 1):

In my case this happened because I opened the workspace in an Eclipse version which missed some of the plugins of the previous Eclipse installation (in fact it was STS before and plain Eclipse J2EE afterwards). Creating a new workspace and importing all projects fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to the Classic theme and restart. It works on Mars.